# invisible special character generated from pdf file

Tags: svg, inkscape

I am trying to insert a pic.pdf file as picture inside my beamer presentation. I used "inkscape" to generate pic.pdf file. There is a special character used inside my svg file (format of the inkscape). The character is visible when I open the pic.pdf file. however it is invisible when I open presentation.pdf file of my presentation generated by texmaker.

Any idea would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Is the character only invisible in the TeXmaker viewer or also in other viewers like Adobe Reader?

Comment: in every viewer, the presentation.pdf file generated by texmaker does not show the special character.

Comment: Possible workaround: "Convert text to paths" in the inkscape pdf save dialogue box.